# BtsActionMapping not understood

Tags: wcf, mapping, adapter, biztalk

Working with BizTalk 2020 WCF custom adapters, a BtsActionMapping is automatically generated. At runtime, however, I get the following error:

> The action <BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
> <Operation Name="Update_SagKontaktID" Action="TypedProcedure/dbo/Update_SagKontaktID" />
> </BtsActionMapping> was not understood.

The two main suggestions for solving this is

1: Make sure that the operation name is the same as the procedure name - WHICH IT IS!

2: Replace the whole BtsActionMapping xml node with only the action - in this case TypedProcedure/dbo/Update_SagKontaktID.

While suggestion 2 actually works, I wonder why the automatically generated BtsActionMapping doesn't work.

Any explanation is highly appreciated!

Comment: Where/how are you setting the operation name? Have you checked the message context to verify it's the same?

Comment: As Ruud has said, where are you setting the Operation name? Also what binding are you using in that WCF-Custom port?

Comment: Thanks Ruud & Dijkgraaf!
I use:
1. Add generated items
2. Consume Adapter Service
3. Select sqlBinding
4. Configure a URL
5. Select Strongly type procedure
This generates the binding info xml containing the BtsActionMapping where Operation name equals the name of the stored procedure

Comment: Where did you get suggestion 1 from? I think it's causing some misunderstanding. Also, how are you sending your messages (direct binding, orchestration, ...)?

Comment: One example of suggestion 1 is found her: http://mylifeismymessage.net/biztalk-wcf-sql-error-btsactionmapping-was-not-understood/.
My point is that the automatically generated - and unaltered - binding info xml resulting from using the Consume Adapter Service Wizard is not understood by BizTalk.

Comment: That is why we kept asking you, where are you setting the Operation name, we mean the one on the message.  The Mapping is how it takes an operation name that is in the context of the message and decides which operation it matches and executes that.   If the operation name on the message doesn't match those defined on the port, it throws that error.   Are you using an Orchestration or is it a message only solution?

Comment: Sorry guys for my delayed understanding - I'm very new to BizTalk. 

I am using an orchestration. The generated binding info xml defines a SendPort (name [xxx]), with a PrimaryTransport: mssql://[yyy]?, TransportType: WCF-Custom and the BtsActionMapping above.

Does that answer your questions? 
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: What's the name of the operation of the send port *inside* your orchestration? That name, by default `Operation_1` as mentioned in the article you linked, should match the name of the operation in your BtsMapping.

Comment: It finally dawned upon an old man what you meant:
When calling the opration from inside the orchestration: OpdaterSagMedKontaktIDStoredProcedurePort but (as seen above) the operation name in the BtsMapping is Update_SagKontaktID!
Mystery solved!
Thanks ever so much!

Comment: @BirgerNiss bit late, but maybe you can post your solution as an answer. It might help others.